# set<string> sorting like numbers

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried to sort set of strings as if they were numbers. 
Each string length can reach to 50 and they don't actually consist of numbers only.
As I understand and searched in the forum, c++ sorts strings lexicographically by default.
Is there a way to change this default behavior to comply my needs?

What I need is like below:

```
    set<string> solution;

    solution.insert("12X451");
    solution.insert("X23454");
    solution.insert("12345");
    solution.insert("12315");
    solution.insert("123111");
    solution.insert("5231");

    for (auto s : solution)
    {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
```

This prints:

```
123111
12315
12345
12X451
5231
X23454
```

What I need is:

```
5231
12315
12345   
123111
12X451
X23454
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior for letters? Are letters always greater than any digit?

Comment: Yes, it is like their ASCII codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass Compare function as constructor argument of set to achieve this effect.

```
bool compare(string s1, string s2)
{
  if(s1.size() == s2.size()) return s1 < s2;
  return s1.size() < s2.size();
}
```

Change above function as per your rules of small.

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/lOBotl)

Or you can pass compare function class as templated argument.

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator ()(const string &s1, const string &s2)
    {
      if(s1.size() < s2.size()) return true;
      if(s1.size() > s2.size()) return false;
      return s1 < s2;
    }
};
...
set<string, cmp> solution;
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/VWCqrL)

Comment: could you provide a small example please?

Comment: A function class is usually better than a function here. It makes it easier to specify the template argument (`Compare` vs `bool(*)(const string &, const string &)`), and gives better scope for inlining.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks. I just wanted to give a quick starting pointer to OP. Now he can use a function class or some other alternative as he wish. I would add function class usage in my answer.

Comment: I guess s1.size() != s2.size() section should be s1.size() == s2.size()